# JavaCC not matching right tokens during error handling

Tags: java, javacc

I'm having some problem using this particular method in order to handle problems in my parser. This is my code provided in Java:

```
void handleErrors(Exception e, int kind, String strError) {
  //ParseException e = generateParseException();
  System.err.println("Errore nel parsing: <" + strError + ">");
  System.err.println(e.toString());
  Token t;

  do {
    t = getNextToken();
  } while(t.kind != kind && t!=null && t.kind != EOF );
}
```

Something is going wrong, when I try to parse this simple function declaration (make reference on AutoIt documentation)

```
Func askjd ($cas)
```

the parser should throw an exception telling me that something is wrong with my function declaration, but it only says general suggestions like:

```
ParseException: Encountered <EOF> at line 1, column 18.
Was expecting one of:
    "If" ...
    "For" ...
    "While" ...
    "Do" ...
    "Switch" ...
    "Func" ...
    "Return" ...
    "EndFunc" ...
    "Const" ...
    <VARNAME> ...
    <NAMEFUNC> ...
```

It should tell me that ONLY `EndFunc` is missing, not other tokens

Comment: Judging by the log, to me it seems like your method isn't called at all.

Comment: The method is called correctly because if I uncomment the code System.err.. it shows me

Errore nel parsing: <" + strError + ">"

Comment: Where is `handleErrors` called from?  Is it called from your code in the .jj file?  If so, you should show us the relevant productions.

Comment: By the way, the code `t.kind != kind && t!=null` does not look right as the second conjunct can never evaluate to false.

Comment: Also you say that "It should tell me that ONLY `EndFunc` is missing, not other tokens."  If you wrote code to generate such a message, you haven't shown it to us.  The JavaCC generated`generateParseException` method computes the set of all legal next tokens.  I don't know AutoIt, but, obviously, if `EndFunc` were the only legal next token, it wouldn't be a very useful language.